# What is causing the Trumpet Sounds that are emited from the sky?

Tags: acoustics, earth, atmospheric-science, geophysics

In these last years, a phenomenon have appeared in several countries (US, Canada, Australia, Russia, Germany, and others).

It consists of sounds like a trumpet coming from our own planet's sky.

[Many related You Tube links here]

> [trumpet sounds from the sky](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=sky+trumpets)

My question is, how true is this theory:

> As our atmosphere becomes more ionised, it'll interact with the
> earth's magnetic fields, causing the ionised gases to vibrate. Vibrate
> fast enough and you get audible sound.

**Or simply, what's the physics behind this phenomena?**

Comment: Hmmmm..... sounds suspiciously like a "Revelation" scenario!

Comment: @WetSavannaAnimalakaRodVance The Revelation correlation obviously comes to mind, but a look at the video shows some quite real and explicable terrestial sources which people quite reasonably report. | FWIW different but useful I long ago saw a magnificent "UFO" in broad daylight - VERY clear - a mile or so away (it seemed) well defined bright sunlight, clear day. I watched it for 10's of seconds as it flew along a local skline above a line of cliffs. If it had then disappeared behind the buildings trees etc on the skyline I could only have reported exactly what I had seen - which was clearly..

Comment: @WetSavannaAnimalakaRodVance ... a UFO -  even though I KNEW it wasn't. | Instead, it suddenly morphed into a lovely [**Sunderland flying-boat**](http://i752.photobucket.com/albums/xx168/jasper999/Decorated%20images/jasper%202/ShortSunderlandFlyingBoat-02_zps6ad95641.jpg)  and no attempt by muy brain would turn it back into a UFO. A good lesson.

Comment: Since I've recorded very similar sounds in Brussels in June 2023 (videos available on demand), and a friend of mine did the same a few years ago in Sydney, I can assure all of you these "sky trumpets" are real and as eerie as you can imagine. What struck me was the duration of the phenomenon (at least 1 hours en half - from 5am, when I woke up, to around 6:30am, but it was fading away by 6:00am) and the strong similarity with the sounds recorded all over the world, and especially the 2012 occurrence in Allen, TX, which is certainly not a hoax.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is a scientific explanation to these "sky trumpets" and I would like to know if scientists have already looked into this phenomenon. I have found nothing conclusive so far. (By the way, the link to the YouTube video is dead.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Occam suggests that the sounds are either able to be explained as typical noises that 'just happen' or are hoaxes. It is unfortunately extremely common for a large number of copy-cat reports of major "strangenesses" to occur once something suitably notable appears on the web.

There are numerous web discussions about these "phenomena".
2023: I've replaced a now dead video link with this -  [Many related You Tube links](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YVScTxRBHFY).

Below I've summarised the points in the now missing video - but if you are interested in the subject the various videos linked to above are worth seeing. His approach is reasonable and logical - this does not make him right, but this is a better than usual approach.

Firstly he demonstrates, with a degree of detail that allows anyone to easily check what he says, that many of the videos are hoaxes, and many clearly use copies of parts of the sound from an early and so far unexplained event.

Next he demonstrates the proven everyday source of some of the sounds which were recorded and reported by others as examples of "strange sounds from the sky.” A good example is an amazingly impressive "celestial chorus" generated by a bulldozer with blade down being used to scrape roughnesses off new concrete at a skate board park.

He then explains typical mechanisms that might explain otherwise unexplained phenomenom.

Finally - some such sounds may have highly esoteric sources - but it does not seem likely that this is in fact the case given the probable alternatives.